# @Temporal annotation does not work when used with @Transactional JUnit tests

Tags: java, oracle11g, jpa-2.0, junit4, spring-boot-test

I have a simple CRUD operations with Spring Boot and Oracle 11g
My Entity class looks like:

```
public class Entity{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int entity_id;
...
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "creation_date", columnDefinition="ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creation_date;

...//setters and getters
}
```

My JUnit looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class EntityTests {
Logger log = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

@Autowired
private EntityRepository  entityRepository;

@Test
public void addEntity(){
    Entity entity= new Entity();
    entity.setFirst_name("Jhon");
    entity.setLast_name("David");
    Entity savedEntity = entityRepository.save(entity);
    log.info(savedEntity.toString());
    Assert.assertEquals(entity, savedEntity);
    //log.info(savedEntity.getCreation_date().toString());
}
```

The last log.info throws NullPointerException when run with @Transactional annotation, But works fine otherwise and DB gets populated with expected values.

Is that how @Transactional behaves or Hibernate does not insert any value for Dates in transactional JUnits?

Comment: Your transaction is not commited, so `Temporal` is not working. You have to commit your transaction. Try `flush` method from repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `@Transactional` annotation on your class, all you changes are not committed into DB. `@CreationTimestamp` and `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)' will not work until changes will be committed.

**What you can do:**

Do not use `@Transactional` in functional test using DB. If you removed annotation your method will be not rollbacked after end of method, so you have to create `@After` method with cleaning up you stuff created by tests:

```
@After
public void cleanUp() {
    entityRepository.deleteAll();
}
```

Second option is to change your save method to `saveAndFlush`. Also you can do this after you saved entity by calling `entityRepository.flush()` method, but here you have to fetch your entity from repository once more time:

```
entityRepository.save(entity);
entityRepository.flush();
Entity savedEntity = entityRepository.findOne(id);
```